# WSDL 1.1 Basic question on endpoint salesforce Apex code

Tags: wsdl, salesforce, apex-code, endpoint

From my WSDL I have the following service part:

```
<service name="BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYService">
  <documentation>SAP Service BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAY via SOAP</documentation>
  <port name="BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYPortType" binding="s0:BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://2.3.4.100:8000/sap/bc/soap/rfc"/>
  </port>
</service>
```

then what will be endpoint reference for this?

I am giving it as  "http://2.3.4.100:8000/sap/bc/soap/rfc" in my salesforce client and it gives the following error.
"This service requires client certificate for authentication procedure."

I am sure that i need to give user name and password not knowing how i can set them in my client which is a Apex code.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you generated your Apex class from the WSDL yet? If not, read the Salesforce docs on [generating classes from WSDLS:](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm)  and post some more details as to what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Yes Paddy i have generated Apex stub class from WSDL. But from my Controller class i am trying to make a callout using @future to this this stub i am able to get in to the method but when the invoke happens since the endpoint is not public and i need to access it through username and password it fails. But I don't know how to set username and password for accessing the endpoint on the stub to consume the webservice on SAP. Hope you understand the issue now. If you want more details i can provide. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: What do you mean by "the endpoint is not public"? Is the web service you are trying to access (the one defined in the WSDL) accessible from the web?

Comment: I mean that this endpoint can not be accessable to everyone until we provide user name and password. Basically i need to set this username and password to stub before making a call. I am not sure how to do this with apex client code. In general let's say in case of java etc. we set it to headers and invoke the webservice. I Don't know how i can do the same in apex client code. Paddy let me know if you want to see my callout method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I imported the Enterprise WSDL and used the uri from the loginResult.  Here's some code from my project:

```
LoginResult loginResult = null; // Login Result (save and make static)
SessionHeader sessionHeader = null; // Session Header (save and make static)
SoapClient soapClient = null; // This is the Enterprise WSDL
SecureStatusClient SecureStatusClient = null; // This is my custom @WebService

// Create Login Request
LoginScopeHeader loginScopeHeader = new LoginScopeHeader
{
    organizationId = configuration["OrganizationId"],
    portalId = configuration["PortalId"]
};

// Call Login Service
string userName = configuration["UserName"];
string password = configuration["Password"];
string securityToken = configuration["SecurityToken"];
using (SoapClient loginClient = new SoapClient())
{
    loginResult = loginClient.login(loginScopeHeader, userName, password + securityToken);

    if (result.passwordExpired)
    {
        string message = string.Format("Salesforce.com password expired for user {0}", userName);
        throw new Exception(message);
    }
}

// Create the SessionHeader
sessionHeader = new SessionHeader { sessionId = loginResult.sessionId };

// Create the SoapClient to use for queries/updates
soapClient = new SoapClient();
soapClient.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(loginResult.serverUrl);

// Create the SecureStatusServiceClient 
secureStatusClient = new SecureStatusServiceClient();
Uri apexUri = new Uri(SoapClient.Endpoint.Address.Uri, "/services/Soap/class/SecureStatusService");
secureStatusClient.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(apexUri);
```

Comment: If i understand correctly you are trying to make a call to Salesforces services from other salesforce module etc. In my case i am trying to consume SAP service inside salesforce apex code. Help is appreciated on this. Thanks